# Heyzap Video Ad Sdk 6.5.1 Android app crash on Fetch

Tags: android, video, crash, fetch, ads

I want to integrate Heyzap 6.5.1 Video AD in Android but application get crashed on fatch the video as I call VideoAd.fetch(); onCreate.
I have complete all steps that is mentioned in given link.
https://developers.heyzap.com/docs/android_sdk_setup_and_requirements

Errors log is given below.

```
07-09 14:13:20.911: E/AndroidRuntime(31346): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11580
07-09 14:13:20.911: E/AndroidRuntime(31346): Process: com.socialink.babyhomeadventure, PID: 31346
07-09 14:13:20.911: E/AndroidRuntime(31346): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 14:13:20.911: E/AndroidRuntime(31346):    at com.heyzap.house.request.FetchManager$1.onFetchResponse(Unknown Source)
07-09 14:13:20.911: E/AndroidRuntime(31346):    at com.heyzap.house.request.FetchManager$2.onSuccess(Unknown Source)
07-09 14:13:20.911: E/AndroidRuntime(31346):    at com.heyzap.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
07-09 14:13:20.911: E/AndroidRuntime(31346):    at com.heyzap.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.postRunnable(Unknown Source)
07-09 14:13:20.911: E/AndroidRuntime(31346):    at com.heyzap.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler$1.run(Unknown Source)
07-09 14:13:20.911: E/AndroidRuntime(31346):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0):

Heyzap support person says that This is a known issue in the SDK version 6.5.1. Expect an updated SDK shortly. I'm waiting for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new HeyZap SDK out (6.5.2) which solves this issue. You can find it at the following link: ﻿http://developers.heyzap.com/sdk/download